# Adding a new line in an Autopilot's collect action

Tags: twilio

I'm asking my bot users a series of questions, some of which ask them to answer Likert-style questions.  When I provide the options for an answer, it would be helpful to put items on a new line.

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "collect": {
                "name": "q1",
                "questions": [
                    {
                        "question": "How much does this bother you?\\n\\n1 = not at all\\n2 = somewhat\\n3 = moderately\\n4 = quite a bit",
                        "name": "q1_score",
                        "type": "Twilio.NUMBER"
                    }
                ],
                "on_complete": {
                    "redirect": "task://question_2"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Ideally, this would return an SMS that says:

```
How much does this bother you?
1 = not at all
2 = somewhat
3 = moderately
4 = quite a bit
```

But what it actually returns is:

```
How much does this bother you?\n\n1 = not at all\n2 = somewhat\n3 = moderately\n4 = quite a bit
```

It doesn't matter if I escape the `\` or not (i.e. neither `\n` nor `\\n` returns the desired result). Trying to use the URL encoded version `%0a` doesn't work either.

Thanks in advance for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Are you using the simulator? The simulator doesn't show new lines I believe, but using `\n` like below should generate the text you wish:

```
"questions": [
                    {
                        "question": {
                            "say": "How much does this bother you? \n 1 = not at all \n 2 = somewhat \n3 = moderately \n4 = quite a bit"
                        },
                        "name": "num",
                        "type": "Twilio.NUMBER"
                    },
...
```

and got

[image: this SMS]

Let me know if this helps at all!

Answer (score -1):

Below worked:

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "collect": {
                "name": "collect_comments",
                "questions": [
                    {
                        "question": "How much does this bother you?\n\n1 = not at all\n2 = somewhat\n3 = moderately\n4 = quite a bit",
                        "name": "comments",
                        "type": "Twilio.NUMBER"
                    }
                ],
                "on_complete": {
                    "redirect": {
                        "method": "POST",
                        "uri": "https://example.com/collect"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]